# How to prevent closing parenthesis from being appended to my formula in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to provide a link that will download an autogenerated spreadsheet, and am attempting to use openpyxl to create the spreadsheet. It is almost working, except for one small detail: when I try to use a formula as the value of the cell, there is a closing parenthesis appended to the end in the saved spreadsheet. This results in a #NAME? error.

Namely, I use something like this as the value

`"=VLOOKUP(A{}, $'lookup_table'.A1:B3, 2, 0) - B{}".format(i + 1, i + 1)`

and the resulting value in the spreadsheet is something like (I open it with LibreOffice Calc)

`=VLOOKUP(A1, $'lookup_table'.A1:B3, 2, 0) - B1)`

Notice the extra parenthesis after the B1.

I have dug around the internet for a solution, but have kept coming up empty. Any guidance on how to make this format correctly?

minimal code example

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws1 = wb.create_sheet(title="lookup_table")
lookup_table = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
for row, (key, value) in enumerate(lookup_table.items()):
    ws1.cell(column=1, row=row + 1, value=key)
    ws1.cell(column=2, row=row + 1, value=value)

for i, value in enumerate(["one", "two", "three"]):
    ws.cell(column=1, row=i + 1, value=value)
    ws.cell(column=2, row=i + 1, value=lookup_table[value])
    ws.cell(
        column=3,
        row=i + 1,
        value="=VLOOKUP(A{}, $'lookup_table'.A1:B3, 2, 0) - B{}".format(i + 1, i + 1),
    )


wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

Comment: When writing formulae it's always worth looking at the XML source because the various programs employ lots of magic such as translations in the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

So the issue actually had nothing to do with openpyxl. But was with LibreOffice.

I looked into the generated xml files, and found that value was exactly as expected. The issue is that LibreOffice Calc references another sheet as `sheet2.A1` and Microsoft Excel references it as `sheet2!A1`. I suppose that since the sheet was being saved as a `.xlsx` it makes sense to use the Excel format.

The file now opens correctly in Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc after updating the string from
`"=VLOOKUP(A{}, $'lookup_table'.A1:B3, 2, 0) - B{}".format(i + 1, i + 1)`

to

`"=VLOOKUP(A{}, 'lookup_table'!A1:B3, 2, 0) - B{}".format(i + 1, i + 1)`

Comment: You are mixing display formula representation and OOXML file format representation. According to section 18.17.2.3 of the OOXML spec the separator between a sheet name and the A1 reference part has to be '!'. Apparently, Excel also handles the non-standard '.' separator character. There are a few cases where the display formula and the file format formulas differ and you need to handle them when you create files yourself.